# Bash scripting: Associated Array only recognizes one value when several given

Tags: bash, array

This lines of a Bash (4.0) Script

> ```
> klang=([string_0]='element_0' [string_1]='element_1' [string_2]='element_2')
> echo "${klang[*]}"     # should output the all set elements
> echo "${#klang[*]}"    # should output the number of set elements
> ```

returns (for some reason):

> ```
> element_2
> 1
> ```

There are no other commands set in this script and I am really new in Bash scripting. What happened to the other elements (`Element_0` and `Element_1`)? 
This really worked perfectly with indexed arrays and numbers and everything, but doesn't work with text – well except for one element which is a bit less than I asked for… Where did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't declare the variable as an associative array, then the

```
klang=([string_0]='element_0' [string_1]='element_1' [string_2]='element_2')
```

is taken as a *normal* array assignment (though note that in `bash` and `ksh93`, *normal* arrays are not really *normal* arrays, they're more *sparse arrays* or associative arrays with keys limited to positive integers).

In `bash`, for a *normal* array, keys are evaluated as arithmetic expressions. As an arithmetic expression, `string_0` evaluates to the content of `$string_0`, and if that's empty, to `0`. So the above is likely to be the same as:

```
klang=([0]='element_0' [0]='element_1' [0]='element_2')
```

So, that's the same as defining `${klang[0]}` (which is the same as `$klang`) 3 times.

That contrasts with `ksh93` arrays (which `bash` mostly copied), where the `a=([x]=y)` syntax is only  supported for associative arrays and would automatically create an associative array when used.

`zsh` associative arrays (which predate `bash` ones by decades) are different again. `zsh` normal arrays are *normal* arrays, `zsh` doesn't support  the bogus `a=([x]=y)` syntax. In `zsh`, you have to declare associative arrays before defining them, and they are defined as:

```
normal_array=(val1 val2 val3)
typset -A associative_array
associative_array=(key1 val1 key2 val2)
associative_array+=(key3 val3...)
```

And `$associative_array` expends to the non-empty *values* like for normal arrays (in undefined order), and `"$associative_array[@]}"` to all the *values* like for normal arrays. `${(k)associative_array}` for the non-empty *keys*, `"${(k@)associative_arrays}"` for all the *keys*, `"${(kv@)associative_array}"` for the keys and values, so you can print the content of an associative array with:

```
printf '%s => %s\n' "${(@kv)associative_array}"
```

That also means the copying an associative array is a lot less cumbersome than with `ksh93`/`bash`:

```
typeset -A B
B=("${(kv@)A}")
```

as opposed to:

```
unset B
typeset -A B
for k in "${!A[@]}"; do B[$k]=${A[$k]}; done
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to first declare your variable (`klang` here) to be an associative array with `bash`:

```
$ declare -A klang
$ klang=([string_0]='element_0' [string_1]='element_1' [string_2]='element_2')
$ echo "${klang[*]}"
element_2 element_0 element_1
$ echo "${#klang[*]}"
3
```

Associative arrays were introduced with `bash` version [4.0](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver4.html).

They were first implemented by `ksh93`, with which this issue doesn't appear.

Comment: **Facepalm!** Of course!!!

Comment: just another question (candidate for facepalm?): What is the way to get, say, the second element (element_1) only - or is this only available for indexed arrays?

Comment: Shell associative arrays are unordered by design so there is no 'second element' to begin with.

Comment: This explains a lot… and is really helpful - thanks a lot!